# Min and max validation using template driven form angular 2

Tags: angular2-forms, angular4-forms

How to set min and max value for text box and how to test min value not greater then max value?

```
<input type="number" placeholder="User Id" required  min="1" max="100" [(ngModel)]="userId" name="userId"  #pickedId="ngModel">
 <div *ngIf="!pickedId.valid && pickedId.touched && !newUserForm.form.valid">
  User id is required!
 </div>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybj7dy?file=app%2Fapp.validator.ts

Comment: @FlySpaceAge:  Your code is not working